# I would like to know which option is the right one: Why did... or Why has...?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense, perfect-aspect

1. Why did the dog make so much noise this night?
2. Why has the dog made so much noise this night?

Comment: "this night" isn't very idiomatic. Do you mean "tonight", "last night", or "that night"? (It is hard to judge how idiomatic a sentence is when part of it is wrong.)

Comment: Welcome! Proofreading questions are not [on-topic here](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please edit the question to tell more about what concerns you about each usage, and what meaning you want.

Comment: 'Why did the dog make so much noise today?' and 'Why has the dog made so much noise today?' are both idiomatic. The first requires that a notional end-point (eg I'm at work, on a night shift, phoning my wife back at home) obtains. The second allows that the dog may start barking in my ear again at any moment.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use the second one.

We usually use the present perfect tense with today, tonight, this week, this month, this year etc.

Why has the dog made so much noise this morning? (It is still morning)

Why did the dog make so much noise this morning? (It is afternoon or evening)

Answer (score 0):

Both the answers are correct.

If you use  past simple, it refers to past tense and finished action.
If you use present perfect, it refers to an action which has happened in the recent past.